# java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed OOP Design bug

Tags: java, sockets, oop

I am writing a college project on banking system for Server - Client communication. One of the requirements is OOP design of an application.

I have a bug around the class where I am implementing methods for communication.

This is a Client Side code. Server Side is implemented similarly and produce same bug.

The outcome of a bug is `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed`

**Class that implements communication methods:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

                            // My custom interface
public class DriveableImpl implements Driveable{

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream out; 
    private ObjectInputStream in; 

    protected DriveableImpl() {}

    // Method that set a socket for a current communication instance
    private void setSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    // Method to connect to a server that takes parameters required to open socket 
    @Override
    public void connect(String ip, int port){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port); // open new socket
            setSocket(socket); // set a socket for a current instance to use in other methods
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Method to close connection with a server
    // Oddly, this method is not bugged and can close socket safely
    @Override
    public void disconnect(){
        sendMessage(0); // send a tag number of a method to a server
        if(socket != null){
            try {
                System.out.println("Closing socket: " + socket);
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Method produce BUG
    // Method that accepts any java object as a parameter and send it through a socket of a current instance
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Object message) {
        try{
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // new object stream with a given socket
            out.writeObject(message); // send an object stream through a socket
            out.flush(); // flush the stream to insure all data is sent and stream is free for new objects
            out.close(); // close a stream for current method invocation
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Method has a BUG
    // Method that reads objects sent by server through a socket
    @Override
    public Object receiveMessage(){
        try{
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // creating new stream to read serialized objects from socket stream
            try {
                return in.readObject(); // return an object that was read from stream 
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                in.close(); // close the stream when object is read and returned
            }
        } catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; // returns null if something went wrong
    }

    // Method that produce BUG
    // Method that processes user registration
    @Override
    public void registration(){
        sendMessage(2); // send a tag number of a method to a server

        try {
            String outcome = (String) receiveMessage(); // waiting for response from server
            System.out.println(outcome);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    // Method that produce BUG
    // Method that processes user login and returns login status as boolean expression
    @Override
    public boolean login(){
        sendMessage(1); // send a tag number of a method to a server

        // Block that receives message from a server about login status, i.e., logged in or reasons for not being logged in
        try {
            outcome = (String) receiveMessage();
            System.out.println(outcome);
            return (boolean)receiveMessage(); // method returns boolean (true/false) that is required 
                                              // to manipulate authentication and issue authorization privileges
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // waiting for response from server

        return false; // if something goes wrong, return false 
    }

} // end of DriveableImpl class
```

**This is standard class that invokes methods and return invoked methods returns:**

```
package ie.gmit.sw.client.methods;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodInvoker implements InvocationHandler{

    private Object returnObject = null; // object that will hold any returns from invoked methods
    private final Driveable userInterface; 


    protected MethodInvoker(Driveable ui) {
        this.userInterface = ui;
    }
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                  throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
                  InvocationTargetException{

        System.out.println("BEFORE");
        returnObject = method.invoke(userInterface, args);
        System.out.println(method.getName());
        System.out.println("AFTER");

        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

**Class that encapsulates binding between MethodInvoker class and class that implements communication methods:**

```
package ie.gmit.sw.client.methods;

import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

                        // Extending a class that implements Driveable Interface
                        // I thought it's a good use of polymorphism 
                        // Used later to create instance of this class of a type Driveable to maximize abstraction
public class IssueDriver extends DriveableImpl {

    private DriveableImpl di = new DriveableImpl(); // creating Object with implemented methods that are required to handle
    private MethodInvoker handler = new MethodInvoker(di); // creating Object that handles/executes methods from implementation class
    // Creating driver through which methods can be called
    private final Driveable driver = (Driveable) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Driveable.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { Driveable.class },
            handler);

    // Constructor that carries driver object
    public IssueDriver() {
        getDriver();
    }

    // returns driver
    private Driveable getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

**Class that uses driver object to invoke methods:**

```
package ie.gmit.sw.client;

import java.util.Scanner;

import ie.gmit.sw.client.methods.Driveable;
import ie.gmit.sw.client.methods.IssueDriver;

public class UserInterface {

    private int option;
    private Scanner input;
    private Driveable driver; // methods driver object 
    private boolean authenticated = false; // Variable to verify authentication and give corresponding authorization rights.


    protected UserInterface() {
        driver = new IssueDriver(); // creating new instance of a methods driver i.e., user options in UI
    }

    protected void menu() {

        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {            /*  ip         port*/
            driver.connect("localhost", 2017); // Method that connects to a server. Excepts parameters with ip address and port number.
        } catch (Exception connect) {
            connect.printStackTrace();
        }


        do{

            if(authenticated == false){

                System.out.println("Choose from these choices");
                System.out.println("-------------------------\n");
                System.out.println("1 - Login");
                System.out.println("2 - Register");
                System.out.println("0 - Quit");

                option = input.nextInt();
                switch(option){
                    case 1: System.out.println("Login");
                            try {
                                authenticated = driver.login(); // Method sends an object with user input for login 
                                                                // and returns status response from the server.
                            } catch (Exception login) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                login.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Registration");
                            System.out.println();
                            try {
                                driver.registration(); // Method sends an object with registration data to the server. 
                                                       // Receives status message from server.
                            } catch (Exception registration) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                registration.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                    case 0: System.out.println("Quit");
                            try {
                                driver.disconnect(); // Method closes connection with server.
                            } catch (Exception discon){
                                discon.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                }
            }
            else if(authenticated == true){
                    // .... 
            }

        }while(option != 0);            
    }
}
```

I tried to narrow the code and isolate problem. 
Class `public class UserInterface` is further instantiated in a run method of a Thread to run an app.

Am I overcooking with OOP design or am I missing some socket programming concepts?

Please ask questions if you don't understand something! 
Suggest how things can be done better in general! 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clsoing the input or output stream of a socket closes the socket.

You should not create a new `ObjectOutputStream` per message, and you should not close it after sending one. The same goes for `ObjectInputStream` when receiving. Use the same ones for the life of the socket.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect that at all! Thanks for an answer. :)

Comment: Hey. I encountered other problem I can't figure out. How can I open streams for input/output?

Comment: I've tried to define 2 new methods ' public void openStreams(Socket socket); ' that creates instances of in/out for current session and 'public Socket getSocket();' that returns socket of a current session in my interface and implemented them. Then I invoke method after connection method in user interface. But nothing happens! Method that is creating in/out never returns and no errors are produced !

Comment: You have to create the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends. You don't really need another method for that: just do it at the same place you create the `Socket`. In the server you should do it at the head of the `run()` method of the thread created to handle each accepted `Socket`.

Comment: I tried to open each stream in separate methods now. Out stream is opening. Opening In stream freezes program and method never finishes.

Comment: I've tried to do it inside same method where socket is created, same result. But yeah, now thinking of it, I am over cooking there now :)

Comment: The constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads a stream header that is placed there by the constructor of `ObjectOutputStream` at the peer, and it will block until that happens. You have to fix this at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Closing either input or the output stream should close the socket. In sendMessage you close the ObjectOutputStream, which likely in turn closes the underlying output stream you passed into the constructor.

Comment: No 'should' or 'likely' about it: that is exactly what happens.